# What is exactly the original_player_id attribute in the Player resource object of Google Api Ruby Client?

Tags: android, ruby, google-api, google-api-ruby-client

The question concerns the official [Google API Ruby client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/) (and https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client)

We can see in its documentation that a Player resource contains an [`original_player_id`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/google-api-client/0.9.2/Google/Apis/GamesV1/Player#original_player_id-instance_method) attribute with this description:

> The player ID that was used for this player the first time they signed into the game in question. This is only populated for calls to player.get for the requesting player, only if the player ID has subsequently changed, and only to clients that support remapping player IDs. Corresponds to the JSON property originalPlayerId

But when I look in [the Google API documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/players#resource-representations), I can't find any reference to this attribute.

So what is this original player id and what are the cases where we need to use it? Is there more detailed documentation on this id?

Is it linked to this Google news: "[Play Games Permissions are changing in 2016](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2016/01/play-games-permissions-are-changing-in.html?)"?

Comment: After a few tests with our Google accounts, it seems that _original_player_id_ contains the Google+ user identifier (probably only if he used to authenticate with Google+ on our app). And _player_id_ contains the Google Play Game player id (maybe not if we continue to request the Google+ authorization, but confirmed in our test  not requesting this permission)